# PHP Native DOMDocument and Simple DOM Parser - is there a size limit?

Tags: php, domdocument

I need to parse the contents of a HTML document (produced by Microsoft Word). Traversing the DOM to get the information/contents I need then outputting the desired as a CSV. Hardly brain surgery I know.

Now as PHP isn't really my thing and I have a tight schedule I was going to use the **PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser** from http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

I noticed that my script isn't working. After trial and error I have realised that this is due to the file size of the HTML files produced by Word (they are 3MB and have as much as 30,000 lines of HTML!). I assume that there is a file size limit to what can be parsed with either the **PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser** and perhaps the native PHP DOMDocument API? If this is the case does anyone know what this limit is? I've been googling for 40 mins now with no success.

Maybe I should just use Node.js?

Comment: 3MB and 30,000 lines of HTML should not pose a problem for ext/DOM.

Comment: I can't tell you about the restrictions of *PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser* because I normally do not use it because I think it is superfluous. You might want to remove some cruft of Word HTML (if you didn't use the dedicated HTML export option in newer versions of Word I never upgraded to since I use Open Office and friends since years and I do not have these problems any longer), you can make use of [Tidy to clean up word html](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/). That might be good for an intermediate solution. I normally use DOMDocument / SimpleXML for documents of that size (<= 500 MB).

Comment: I use the Simple HTML DOM Parser for several years now and I can say it works pretty good except that it needs some tweaks to reduce memory usage (all is now by reference) and a smart seek cache. I use it in my framework to merge XML/HTML into a template to produce HTLM pages. Nice thing is that you can use a jQuery/CSS like syntax. Without optimizing (for example the by reference parameter passing) it reach easily 20MB to 30MB memory usage. With the optimization it is beyond 4 to 7MB depending on the size of your document resources. So, it is good but need some tweaking.

Answer (score 10):

PHP "Native" [`DOMDocument`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/DOMDocument) and its little sister [`SimpleXMLElement`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement) do not have a hardencoded size limit,  but they are limited by the memory you allow PHP to use (see [PHP memory limit<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/memory-limit)).

Also you must not assume that loading a 100 MB XML or HTML file will consume an equal size of memory. It most often is much less memory than the file-size (e.g. a fifth or a tenth or even, depends a bit on the XML so you can not just say factor X here instead you need to metric your own if you want to obtain precise information).

The file-size you give in your question - 3 MB - is rather small I'd say. Maybe not small for a HTML file in the internet but small for the [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) based PHP extensions. You can find out about the memory usage in PHP when loading that file by using [`memory_get_usage()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/memory_get_usage).

If you have really large XML files - then normally X(HT)ML - let's say 1.5 *gigabytes* - parsing with DOMDocument will take a lot of lead time. Then using the [`XMLReader`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/XMLReader) will allow you to parse the document without loading it into memory (completely). But it is no silver bullet, because you still have the parse-time but you can better control what to parse and which parts to skip so you have more room to control optimizations in PHP userland.

---

The PHP library [*PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser*<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) does not impose a specific size limit as well. However it's not a binary extension of PHP but in PHP userland. So you need to better understand what exactly that library does (see [`simple_html_dom.php` in HEAD revision](http://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/simple_html_dom.php)). If you review the code you can see it is a parser purely written in PHP. This is because it was original written for PHP 4 where `DOMDocument` with `DOMDocument::loadHTML` did not exist yet.

As you can imagine, a PHP extension can manage memory much better than a PHP library written in PHP code. Especially when it comes to tree structures which a HTML Document object model is (this sentence is not true in its own, however developing this memory optimized takes a lot of work and a good design which is not always easy to create nor to maintain).

However: Since many years now *it is not necessary to use that library any longer*. Many PHP users do not know that and they find outdated code examples using that once popular library. The library *PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser* even still gets suggested from time to time here on Stackoverflow.

So the best suggestion I can give is: Unless you do not need to write PHP 4 compatible code, do not use that library at all and do not care about its limits. Instead port your code to [`DOMDocument::loadHTML()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/DOMDocument.loadHTML).

Comment: I use the Simple HTML DOM Parser for several years now and I can say it works pretty good except that it needs some tweaks to reduce memory usage (all is now by reference) and a smart seek cache. I use it in my framework to merge XML/HTML into a template to produce HTLM pages. Nice thing is that you can use a jQuery/CSS like syntax. Without optimizing (for example the by reference parameter passing) it reach easily 20MB or 30MB memory usage. With the optimization it is beyond 4 to 7MB depending on the size of your resources. So, it is good but need some tweaking.

Comment: @Erwinus: DOMDocument has xpath - often much more powerful than CSS selects - but if you like to prefer CSS selectors, there are many adapter libs that let you use CSS selectors instead. Just saying as I see your comment first here months later.

Answer (score 3):

PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser has a limit of 600KB.

```
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000);
```

You can, of course, edit your copy of the library and change this constant.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the insight. I was getting no result from file_get_html() from some URLs and looked like it was the html file size limit which was the issue. I increased the limit and now it fetches URLs contents just fine into the dom. Thank you @Barmar