# Grab price from URL

Tags: php, dom, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get a price from any given URL using simple-html-dom.
The example code i used, which works well is from here:
http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/06/extract-url-content-like-facebook-with-php-and-jquery

```
//Include PHP HTML DOM parser (requires PHP 5 +)
include_once("Includes/simple_html_dom.inc.php");

//get URL content
$get_content = file_get_html($get_url);
```

Getting the title works fine:

```
//Get Page Title 
        foreach($get_content->find('title') as $element) 
        {
            $page_title = $element->plaintext;
        }
```

However when trying to read span elements to get a price looking for a currency symbol i'm getting nothing.

```
    //Get Price
    foreach($get_content->find('span') as $element) 
    {

        $price = $element->plaintext;

        if (strpos($price, '$') !== FALSE)
            {
                $page_price = $price;
            }

        else { $page_price = '0.00';}
    }
```

Comment: what is your get url?

Comment: From any given url? For that you'll want a regex.

Comment: Yes any given URL, do i need a regex if im just searching for a $/£ sign?

Comment: no you don't. as you've already noticed, strpos() will suffice ^^

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, lol like your test link. Let me tinker some more

Comment: Try this URL as well i can get everything but the price from the span http://www.heals.co.uk/invt/cohenbrass?Source=119_74&gclid=CICJm5Suh8QCFW3LtAodxTAAJg this is what i get back Was , ,  ,Now , ,Was , ,  ,Now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this kindof works, unfortunately, DOMDocument is retarded and will sometimes add < script> content to textContent ... and i don't know how to do this with "simple_html_dom", but i think it'd be easy to port ;) (it would surprise me if its any smarter than DOMDocument though, but who knows..)

Edit: updated the code to work around the < script > tag issue/bug with DOMNode->textContent

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$html=file_get_contents("http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0081IDX84");
$domd=new DOMDocument();
@$domd->loadHTML($html);
$matches=array();
foreach($domd->getElementsByTagName("script") as $node){
//DOMDocument is retarded, and will sometimes add <script> content to 
//textContent, so removing them..
$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}


foreach($domd->getElementsByTagName("span") as $node){
    if(strpos($node->textContent, '$') !==false){
        $matches[]=$node->textContent;
    }
}
if(php_sapi_name() === 'cli'){
    var_dump($matches);
    } else {
echo '<pre>';
ob_start();
var_dump($matches);
echo htmlentities(ob_get_clean());
echo '</pre>';
}
```

you can see the code live in action here http://codepad.viper-7.com/y1b0y3

Comment: Thanks this seems to have gotten me further using DomDocument() rather than simple_html_dom(). it seems simple_html_dom is quite outdated now :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805805/php-native-domdocument-and-simple-dom-parser-is-there-a-size-limit

Comment: as a nice bonus, DOMDocument is very simmilar to traversing the DOM with javascript :D and is likely to just get better and better/kept up-to-date as newer versions of php (and libxml) is released (unlike simple_html_dom , who's developtment seemingly ended in 2012 - http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/simplehtmldom/ )

Answer (score -1):

strpos() will just return the position of "$", not the price. Also the variable will get overwritten after each wrap, so you probably want to break out of the loop once you found the right value.