# Cannot print values from a table` columns using PHP DOM

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to print this table using the DOM library:

[image]

I want all the values from each column to be printed separately, probably in an array. Here is my code so far:

```
  foreach ($descrDom->find(".tbl-fit") as $key => $td) { 
    $descr=$td->plaintext ."\n";
    //var_dump($descr);   
  }
```

At this point my code is printing all the data from each html element in the table including the table headers.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use a PHP native DOM parser library like `DOMDocument`  [see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805805/php-native-domdocument-and-simple-dom-parser-is-there-a-size-limit)

Comment: I am using the file: `simple_html_dom.php` which has all the libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this

```
$column= 0; // The column number you want to be printed
$cell = 1;
while ($b = $descrDom->find("table.tbl-fit tr", $cell)) {
    $result[] = $b->children($column)->plaintext;
    $cell++;
}

print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
ALFA ROMEO MITO (955_)
ALFA ROMEO MITO (955_)
FIAT 500 (321_)
FIAT 500 (321_)
FIAT 500 C(321_)
.. etc
```

If you want to fetch the type column just change `$column`variable to 1 and so on.

Comment: However the `"table.tbl-fit tr"` element is not found when I made `var_dump`, returns for `$result`- NULL

Comment: @Hrisi Then your table has no class named `tbl-fit`. Make sure the class you're looking for is the one that's associated with the table.

Comment: Yes, it has to be  `div.tbl-fit tr` because the html element is div, not table :). Thank you!